# How can I make operators on subclasses return the subclass type?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm in the progress of converting a piece of code from one geometric library to another. In my current code, I have a lot of specialized Point classes, and I'd rather have a single templated one. The new templated one, has an overloaded addition operator, defined as;

```
template<typename To>
Point<T, N> operator+(const Point<To,N>& p) const;
```

Where `T` is the contained type, and `N` is the dimensional arity of the point.

In order to provide the old usage interface, I had to subclass the Point class. Mainly by aliasing some members, and adding a few functions;

```
// Old library, could be indexed by var.x, ...
// New library, can only be indexed via. var[i]
int& x = data[0];
int& y = data[1];
int& z = data[2];

// Old library, supplied this function, new one didn't.
void subclass_function();
```

This works like a charm, and this replacement does it's job in most call-sites throughout the program. That is, unless there's an arithmetic operation, followed by a function provided by the compatibility class, say:

```
IntPoint3 index;
// The scalar multiplication results in the Point<int, 3>.
(index * 2).subclass_function();
```

Error: The `Point<int, 3>` does not have the `subclass_function()` defined.

What is the suggested solution to this? - (i.e. get the operator to return the subclass type)

Note1: I'd rather edit the Point class, than wrap all overloads of the arithmetic operators, in each specialized subclass.

Note2: The specialized subclasses doesn't add state.

Comment: I'm confused about the title of the question.  What does your question have to do with `operator==`?

Comment: You have to redefine all the operators in the derived class to do this, unfortunately.

Comment: @VaughnCato he means that he has `Base::operator+` returning `Base` , and he wants the expression `derived_a + derived_b` to return a `Derived`.

Comment: If every `Point<int, 3>` should be able to replace a `IntPoint3`, then `Point<int, 3>` *is a* `IntPoint3`, and the inheritance should be the other way around.

Comment: Oh, you can use the CRTP if you really want to mess with inheritance here.

Comment: Also, `operator+` should be a non-member function that is implemented via `operator+=`

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Wow, ok.  Got lost in lexical ambiguity.  I've changed the title of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Use the curiously repeating template pattern (CRTP).

The base `template` class `Point_impl` takes its derived type as an argument.

It returns the derived type from its operators.

```
template<class T, unsigned N, class D>
struct Point_impl {
  D* self() { return static_cast<D*>(this); }
  D const* self() const { return static_cast<D const*>(this); }

  template<typename U, typename D2>
  D operator+(Point_impl<U,N,D2> const& o) const {
    auto retval = *self();
    retval += o;
    return retval;
  }
};
```

Then your derived:

```
struct Bob:Point_impl<int,3,Bob>{
  //...
};
```

etc.

I find `static_assert` in `self` with `is_base_of` wise as well, as it catches some typos.

Comment: Guess you're on your phone again or is today the "save the space bar day"? ;) (you got a stray `'`)

Comment: @dyp making bbq, yep.  Do not use any autocorrect, because it does worse things to code than my typos!